# how to free a struct pointer inside a function that takes the pointer as argument

Tags: c, pointers, struct

edited*

I am learning about structs and pointers, and part of the assignment I am working on asked me to free up the space malloc'd for a struct pointer. The pointer is passed as an argument inside a function, and I was wondering if I can free the space inside the function? The pointer is declared in the main file, and all the function code is in a separate file. Below is my code, and when its tested Valgrind would say memory leak at the line where dict is declared in main. Any tips on how to approach this would be greatly appreciated.

the code that generates the struct pointer:

```
typedef struct dict_list {
char* key;
char* val;
struct dict_list* next;
} dict_list_t;


typedef struct dict {
    dict_list_t* head;
    size_t size;
} dict_t;

dict_t* dict_create () {
  dict_t *ret = (dict_t *) malloc(sizeof(dict_t));
  ret -> head = NULL;
  ret -> size = 0;
  return ret;
}
```

it is then called in the main file:

```
int main (int argc, char** argv) {
  dict_t* dict = dict_create ();
```

the function that is called to remove the list as a whole

```
void dict_destroy (dict_t* dict) {
  dict_list_t* el = dict->head;
  dict_list_t* next_val;

  while(el){
    next_val = el->next;
    dict_del(dict,el->key); //removes the key/value pair in dict if a matching key is found 
    el = next_val;
  }
free(el);
free(dict->head);
free (dict);
}
```

this is the error message I get from Valgrind

```
HEAP SUMMARY:
==1801801== 16 bytes in 1 blocks are still reachable in loss record 1 of 2
==1801801==    at 0x4C34F0B: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:307)
==1801801==    by 0x400A77: dict_create (dict.c:18)
==1801801==    by 0x400DEC: main (main.c:11)
```

Comment: There's not enough here to see what the problem might be.  Please update your question with a [mcve].

Comment: @dbush I just added some more code, would this be more clear?

Comment: What is the problem you observe? The code you show seems adequate to free a pointer within a function taking it as parameter. You are aware that the pointer (or the memory it is/was pointing to) is freed, even if the value of the pointer does not change, aren't you?

Comment: It's still possible that `dict_clear` is forgetting to free something.

Comment: You have shown more code. Pleae upgrade to a [mre] which demonstrates your observed problem.

Comment: "would this be more clear?" Here's how to tell.  Take the exact code you posted, and paste it into brand new files.  Can you compile those files and run them, and get the same error that you are asking about?  If not, it isn't a [mcve] because it isn't *reproducible*.

Comment: Getting closer, but still not there.  Anyone else should be able to copy/paste the code in your question *as is*, compile and run it, and get the same results you do.

Comment: @Yunnosch so to fully destroy the linked list constructed, I would have to empty out the values and then I'll be able to free up the memory space?

Comment: I would like to discuss that based on a MRE. Could you provide one?

Comment: @Yunnosch sorry I don’t think I know what that is 

Comment: MRE, [mre], it is what you have been asked multiple times to provide, each time with a link you seem to ignore. I intentionally used the acronym only, in order to get you to look at those feedback comments from a new angle. So, please read what the link refers to (i.e. not only the blue words) and then try to provide one.

Comment: @Yunnosch I actually found my mistake while trying to write the MRE, thank you for your help!

Comment: In that case please create an answer and share what you learned. Finding answers while creating a MRE is by the way almost a common occurence. That is why many users here insist on seeing MREs instead of "only the relevant code" or worse, "all code". And if you improve your question to the point that others could have found your answer, then you might end up having a nice and upvoteable Q/A pair.

Comment: @Yunnosch Got it. This is my first time actually posting on this site, thanks for the tips!

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please do not edit solution announcements into the question. Accept (i.e. click the "tick" next to it) one of the existing answer, if there are any. You can also create your own answer, and even accept it, if your solution is not yet covered by an existing answer. Compare https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's perfectly fine for a function to `free` a pointer that was `malloc`ed in some other function. However, it's extremely important to write a documentation comment that lets the person calling the function know that the pointer is being freed. We can't leave that stuff to chance in C.

---

In your current edit, we see that `dict_t` has a pointer field `head`, but we don't know if `dict_clear` frees that pointer. That might be your problem.

Comment: so I'll have to free the head and size individually before I can free dict as a whole? I have added more code hopefully it would make it more clear to see

Comment: You have to free each malloc'd pointer individually, even if it's inside a struct. The `size` field is not a pointer, so it wouldn't make sense to free that.

Comment: I actually forgot to free(el->val) in a function that was being called in dict_clear, which is a field in dict->head. Thanks for the help!